# Hibernate Spatial and PostGIS Primary Key Issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I am new with PostGIS, and I am using PostGIS with Hibernate Spatial and Spring framework. The problem is that the primary key is not set automatically and I get the following error when inserting data into the DB:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
Detail: Failing row contains (null,name , country).
```

I have tested the code on MySQL and it works correctly. However, when using Hibernate Spatial and PostGIS it gives me the mentioned error. Here is the model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    ...
}
```

Here is the code for inserting the data:

```
 public void addPerson(Person p) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(p);
}
```

And here are the dependencies in Maven:

```
postgis-jdbc: 1.5.2
postgresql: 8.4-702.jdbc3
hibernate-entitymanager: 4.0.0.Final
hibernate-core: 4.0.0.Final
hibernate-spatial: 4.0
commons-dbcp: 1.4
spring version: 4.0.3.RELEASE
```

And Hibernate configurations:

```
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>it.polimi.thesis.model.Person</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.ddl-auto">update</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

I would appreciate any help. Please let me know if any additional info is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some search this solution worked:

```
@Id
@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
private int id;
```

I also added the following the hibernate configurations:

```
<beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
```